# How to prevent calling of MPI_Finalize() within class destructor?

Tags: c++, mpi

I have a class that creates a new `MPI_Datatype` in its constructor and then deletes it in its destructor. However, the presence of the deletion of the custom datatype somehow triggers the calling of `MPI_Finalize()` within the destructor.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "mpi.h"

class foo
{
public:
    MPI_Datatype M_INT;

    foo(MPI_Comm comm) 
    {
        MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &id);
        printf("%2d: Constructing foo.\n", id);
        MPI_Type_dup(MPI_INT, &M_INT);
    }
    
    ~foo() 
    {
        printf("%2d: Destructing foo.\n", id);
        MPI_Type_free(&M_INT);                  // problematic line
    }
private:
    int id;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    foo bar(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    MPI_Finalize();
    
    return 0;
}
```

This produces a runtime error that complains `Attempting to use an MPI routine after finalizing MPICH`. Removing the deletion of the custom `MPI_Datatype` within the destructor is a temporary workaround. However, I would like a better, proper solution. If you know why this is happening and how to solve it, kindly explain. Thank you.

---

### EDIT:

As per the suggestions in the comments, I have tried the following. This still has exactly the same problem as my earlier example code.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "mpi.h"

class M_Comm
{
public:
    MPI_Comm p;
    int already_finalised;

    M_Comm(const MPI_Comm& _comm) : p(_comm) {}
    ~M_Comm()
    {
        MPI_Finalized(&already_finalised);
        if (!already_finalised)
            MPI_Finalize();
    }
};

class foo
{
public:
    MPI_Datatype M_INT;

    foo(const M_Comm& comm) 
    {
        MPI_Comm_rank(comm.p, &id);
        printf("%2d: Constructing foo.\n", id);
        MPI_Type_dup(MPI_INT, &M_INT);
    }
    
    ~foo() 
    {
        printf("%2d: Destructing foo.\n", id);
        MPI_Type_free(&M_INT);                  // problematic line
    }
private:
    int id;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    M_Comm comm_std(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    foo bar(comm_std);
    MPI_Finalize();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I guess the destructor is called when you exit the scope (e.g. after `return 0`). Try putting your type in its own scope (e.g. `{foo bar(MPI_COMM_WORLD);}`) and see if the compiler does what you expect.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet Yes, that is another workaround, but I might need the object later on.

Comment: You're trying to combine object-oriented programming and straight imperative programming. You need to make a communicator object, and do `MPI_Finalize` in its destructor, which will get called at the end of your program. (You can get inspiration by looking at C++ MPI libraries, such as MPL.) By the way: `foo(MPI_Comm comm)` that is passing by value. You implicitly use the fact that `MPI_Comm` is a handle. If it is an object, you are duplicating your communicator here. Use: `foo ( const MPI_Comm& comm)`.

Comment: an other option is to protect the MPI call of the destructor with `MPI_Finalized()`

Comment: @VictorEijkhout I really thought the last suggestion might do the trick, but it did not. Even when we pass a reference to the communicator to the constructor the class, the destructor still calls `MPI_Finalize()` if there is the `MPI_Type_free(&M_INT)` line.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet How exactly? I am not using an explicit `MPI_Finalize()` in the destructor. There is no such thing as `MPI_Prevent_Finalize()`, so even if I have a variable that tells me whether `MPI_Finalize()` has been called or not, what would I do with that information? When we are inside the scope of the destructor, we already know that one `MPI_Finalize()` has been called from the `main` function.

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe read @Giles comment carefully. The problem is that your destructor is called at the end of the program, that is, after you have done Finalize. Do what I suggested: make an object for your communicator. That `const&` stuff I mentioned is just cosmetics.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Thank you, but I may not have fully understood what you asked of me. Kindly check my edit. Is this what you meant? This still does not solve the problem. If you meant something else, would you terribly mind if I asked you to please write an answer with a working example? Thank you very much.

Comment: You still have `MPI_Init` and `MPI_Finalize` in your main program. They need to be done when you create the communicator object. Your program is halfway between traditional programming and object-oriented. That's not going to work.

Comment: @VictorEijkhout Thank you. That helps. Is there any disadvantage to going fully object-oriented in this manner?

Comment: Note your initial question did not call `MPI_Finalize()` in the destructor. Did you mean to call `MPI_Comm_free()` instead?

Comment: Keep in mind that you cannot call `MPI_Init()` after `MPI_Finalize()`, so using a `MPI_Obj` does not look like a great fit to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@VictorEijkhout suggested the following solution in his comments. The idea is to create a communicator object which calls `MPI_Init` and `MPI_Finalize` in its constructor and destructor, then pass that object to other functions or classes for further manipulation.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "mpi.h"

class MPI_Obj
{
public:
    MPI_Comm COMM = MPI_COMM_WORLD;
    int already_finalised;

    MPI_Obj(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
        MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    }
    ~MPI_Obj()
    {
        MPI_Finalized(&already_finalised);
        if (!already_finalised)
            MPI_Finalize();
    }
};

class foo
{
public:
    MPI_Datatype M_INT;

    foo(const MPI_Obj& mpi) 
    {
        MPI_Comm_rank(mpi.COMM, &id);
        printf("%2d: Constructing foo.\n", id);
        MPI_Type_dup(MPI_INT, &M_INT);
    }
    
    ~foo() 
    {
        printf("%2d: Destructing foo.\n", id);
        MPI_Type_free(&M_INT);
    }
private:
    int id;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    MPI_Obj comm_std(argc, argv);
    foo bar(comm_std);
    
    return 0;
}
```